# Display base R and ggplot2 plots in a multi-window layout in R

Tags: r, layout, plot, ggplot2

Given the following examples below, how possible is it for me to combine base R plots with ggplot2 plots in a multi-window layout? 
I would like to add the ggplot2 objects (`p,p1`) to an open `x11()` device. For some reasons I will appreciate a solution that does not require that I obtain `p,p1` for base R plots.

```
if (dev.cur() == 1) x11(width=15,height=15)
par(mfrow = c(2,2), oma = c(0,0,0,0) + 0.1,mai = c(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0), mar = c(0,0,0,0) + 0.1)


    # Generate some data
    x<-1:10; y1=x*x; y2=2*y1
    plot(x, y1, type="b", pch=19, col="red", xlab="x", ylab="y")
    # Add a line
    lines(x, y2, pch=18, col="blue", type="b", lty=2)
    # Add a legend
    legend(1, 95, legend=c("Line 1", "Line 2"),
           col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
#---------------------------------------------------------    
    # Generate some data
    x<-1:10; y1=x*x; y2=2*y1
    plot(x, y1, type="b", pch=19, col="red", xlab="x", ylab="y")
    # Add a line
    lines(x, y2, pch=18, col="blue", type="b", lty=2)
    # Add a legend
    legend(1, 95, legend=c("Line 1", "Line 2"),
           col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------    
            library(ggplot2)
            data(ToothGrowth)
            ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
            head(ToothGrowth)
            p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
              geom_violin()
            p
#----------------------------------------------------------------
        p1 <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
          geom_violin()
        p1

        library(latticeExtra)
        grid.arrange(p, p1,ncol=2)# I can use grid.arrange to display ggplot objects.
```

Comment: `gridBase` is a thing, but it looks finicky.

Comment: I haven't tried using `gridBase` but there's [a vignette here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/vignettes/gridBase.pdf).

Comment: @alistaire It's pretty low-level but works well. Knowing grid well (which I don't) helps understanding it.